# Add new columns without using Alter

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to add new columns to an existing table without using alter statement?

Comment: what is the problem with `ALTER` ?

Comment: Why would you not use ALTER

Comment: Drop and create...

Comment: If you need a column at run-time, you can go for `computed` column or `literal character string` column

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Actually, this question was asked to me in an interview.The interviewer asked me if the processing time for the execution of an alter statement exceeds the loading time of the table having large no. of columns, what alternative can be used instead of alter statement to add new columns to the table.

Comment: @A-004, that would have been good detail to add to the question in the first place.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: You mean after that one? ;-) Sure.

Comment: Yes :P Suppose we have to create tables (e-Commerce database) with categories & subcategories i.e we have to normalize the tables which in turn significantly increases tables volume causing performance issues.Is there any alternative for normalization process i.e if how can I prevent creating multiple subcategory tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other people are answering unequivocally "no, it is not possible." This is the answer to your literal question. But I'm wondering why you ask the question.

One of the biggest pain points of MySQL is that using `ALTER TABLE` locks the table while you're making a change like adding a column, and the more data in your table, the longer this lasts while it restructures the table. I'm guessing this is the issue you have, and you're trying to get an alternative that doesn't block access to the table while you're adding a new column.

(In the future, it would help folks give you the best answers if you explain more about what you're trying to do.)

The answer to this question is **yes, there is a solution:** [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) is a free tool that accomplishes this.

You use it just like you would use ALTER TABLE, but you use it at the command-line instead of in an SQL query.

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=sakila,t=actor
```

In this example, the database name is `sakila` and the table name is `actor`. The script does a lot of work behind the scenes:

- Create a table like the original table, but empty of rows
- ALTER TABLE to add the column or whatever other alteration you told it. You can do anything you would normally do with ALTER TABLE. In fact, it's doing ALTER TABLE for you, against the empty copy table.
- Copy rows from the original table to the new table in the background.
- Create triggers to capture any changes made to the original table while it's gradually copying the bulk of the data.
- Swap the names of the new table (with the extra column) and the original table, once all data has been copied.
- Drop the original table.

This has a few caveats, like the original table must have a primary key, and must not have existing triggers.

It tends to take longer than doing a traditional ALTER TABLE, but since it's not blocking access to the original table, it's still more convenient.

Does this help?

Comment: Gracious for your reply.

Comment: Actually, this question was asked to me in an interview.The interviewer asked me if the processing time for the execution of an alter statement exceeds the loading time of the table having large no. of columns, what alternative can be used instead of alter statement to add new columns to the table. My answer to the interviewer was similar to the one you mentioned above.Just needed to clarify it further.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add new columns to an existing table without using the alter statement?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add new columns to an existing table without using alter statement?

I don't think it's impossible.
However I'm not sure what you want to do.

lets say you have a table

select * from Store

and you want just export the data or perhaps you want to do something with that data like a selection. but you don't want to STORE the data in your Database

you can just fill a value and give it a name

select
'Test' as name,
*
from Store

this will populate your column with the value your entered.

[data results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9myNJ.png)